# How to fill a large rectangular div with smaller square divs no matter the ratio and screen size?

Tags: css, html

I am creating a simple to use site where by one of the sections is a projects section, the div  for the section will hopefully be the same size as the window (from and up to a certain resolution). I want to fill said rectangular div with square divs each the same size, enough to fill the rectangle div and leave no gaps nor overlap the edges of the rectangle div and so on. what would be the best approach for this as I am stumped at the moment.

Comment: You need them independent from each other?

Comment: @Mark The question you should be asking is "where is your code?"

Comment: I didnt feel like such a question warranted the posting of my code, as i dont have issues with my code as such but rather needing a method or idea or such

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try a responsive way for this, setting the smaller div height and width by dividing the small width to the big ones width 
Dont ask me how, im stunned by responsive css too :O

Answer (score -1):

Using CSS HTML and Jquery, something like this would work.

```
<div id="sqr_contain">
<div class="sqr">1</div>
<div class="sqr">2</div>
<div class="sqr">3</div>
<div class="sqr">4</div>
<div class="sqr">5</div>
<div class="sqr">6</div>
<div class="sqr">7</div>
<div class="sqr">8</div>
<div class="sqr">9</div>
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var a = $("#sqr_contain").height();
   $(".sqr").height(a/3);
   });
</script>

<style>
    #sqr_contain{
    width:100%;
    max-width:900px;
    height:900px; /*This can be set to anything, contained squares will auto adjust, 900 will just keep them square */
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;   /* Firefox 1, probably can drop this */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   /* Safari 3-4, also probably droppable */
    box-sizing:        border-box;   /* Everything else */
    background: #888;
    }
.sqr {
    width:33.32%;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;   /* Firefox 1, probably can drop this */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   /* Safari 3-4, also probably droppable */
    box-sizing:        border-box;   /* Everything else */
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```